# Event dispatched when network is disconnected while downloading files (URLs) for URLStream object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, networking, air

I am creating an AIR application which downloads file from a server. I am using URLstream object with complete, progress, IOError, security error and HTTP status events. I am not getting an event if the network is disconnected when the download is in progress. Please can anyone tell me which event is dispatched?

Thanks,
Anahas

Answer (score 1):

You should get the IOError event in case the network gets disconnected. If you're not getting it, you either didn't add a listener for that event, or you added it on the wrong object, or there's a framework/Flash bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a separate set of events that AIR uses to communicate connectivity status.  They can monitor services, servers or just "connectivity" ( do I have network ).  [Monitoring network connectivity](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html)

I agree with bug-a-lot though, at some point you should get an IOError but you might have to wait for a timeout to occur.

Answer (score 0):

is there way to change the time-out for IOError while loading using urlstream ?
sometimes even though network is disconnected i dont get the event but its not very definitive.